# Laravel Decimal Column Indexing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, indexing, database-indexes

I am using the commonly known reddit 'hot' algorithm on my table 'posts'. Now this hot column is a decimal number like this: 'XXXXX,XXXXXXXX'

I want this column to be an index, because when I order by 'hot', I want the query to be as fast as possible. However, I am kind of new to indexes. Does an index need to be unique?

If it has to be unique, would this work and be efficient?

```
$table->unique('id', 'hot');
```

If it does not have to be unique, would this be the right approach?

```
$table->index('hot');
```

Last question: would the following query be taking advantage of the index?

```
 Post::orderBy('hot', 'desc')->get()
```

If not, how should I modify it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not 100% sure but almost 100% sure the answer is yes to all 3 questions. (though I think `unique` only needs 1 parameter). Doing an `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY hot DESC` can verify whether your index is being used (but it should be).

Comment: Wait. So at the moment, I am doing $table->index('hot'), because the column is not unique. Using the explain query, it did not use any keys unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Do not make it UNIQUE unless you need the *constraint* that you cannot insert duplicates.

Phrased differently, a `UNIQUE` key is two things:  an `INDEX` (for speedy searching) and a "constraint" (to give an error when trying to insert a dup).

`ORDER BY hot DESC` *can* use `INDEX(hot)` (or `UNIQUE(hot)`).  I say "can", not "will", because there are other issues where the Optimizer may decide not to use the index.  (Without seeing the actual query and knowing more about the the dataset, I can't be more specific.)

If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, then neither of these is of any use:  `INDEX(id, hot)`; `UNIQUE(id, hot)`.  Swapping the order of the columns makes sense.  Or simply `INDEX(hot)`.

A caveat:  `EXPLAIN` does not say whether the index is used for `ORDER BY`, only for `WHERE`.  On the other hand, `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` does give more details.  Try that.

(Yes, `DECIMAL` columns can be indexed.)

Comment: Thank you for all the information! But I'm pretty sure that "EXPLAIN" does show whether or not index is used? If I force it to use it, it does show it.