# MySQL Index for Decimal Column ORDER BY Query

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, sql-order-by, database-indexes

I have a table 'posts' with a column 'hot' (reddit algorithm). 'hot' is a decimal: XXXXX,XXXXXXX

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY hot DESC
```

Now I would like this query to use an index for 'hot'. I tried

```
ADD INDEX hot_index(hot)
```

and SHOW INDEXES FROM posts shows me that the index was indeed created.

However, when I run my query with 'EXPLAIN' before it, I can see that MySQL is not using the index for ordering. Why? How can I change that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could try index hinting by `USE INDEX (hot_index)` making the query `SELECT * FROM posts USE INDEX (hot_index) ORDER BY hot DESC` But maybe MYSQL has already discounted your index as no real help

Comment: Yeah that doesn't help unfortunately. I also tried using INT instead of a decimal, but that doesn't change anything either.

Comment: if "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY hot DESC"  is the query being used, then you need all the rows from the table and Optimizer would have ignored it as it is a Full table scan. As RiggsFolly  suggested you can try USE INDEX or FORCE INDEX hints in the query if you want to definitely use the index.

Comment: Use FORCE INDEX hint.   If index is still not used, put a where clause on the hot column,  If index is still not picked up, then run OPTIMIZE/ANALYZE  table command and check.

Comment: thank you, forcing worked and it did take longer than without the index.

Comment: (1) see my answer in your [_dup question_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053029/laravel-decimal-column-indexing) .  (2) Let's see the entire `EXPLAIN`; if it does not say "filesort", then it used the index.

Comment: `USE` and `FORCE` may help _today_, but bite you _tomorrow_.

Comment: but indexing a decimal is rather strange no? because a decimal values has so many decimals combinations involved imagine all the 0,00001, 0,00002  or 0,00200 etc.. till the full range combination of the field as a key.. looks like of no real use right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously MySQL decides that it is faster to read the entire table sequentially and perform the sort on-the-fly rather than read the index (and thus having the sort order), but then have to access the posts records one by one. This is a valid assumption.

If this results in a performance issue, then you may want a covering index, starting with the sort column:

```
create index idx on posts(hot, col1, col2, col3 ...)
```

With `select *` you'd have to include all columns in that index.

With a covering index, the DBMS can get all values from the index itself and thus doesn't have to access the table anymore.

Anyway, it would still be possible that the DBMS prefers to read the table sequentially, but it is very likely it would not.

Another point is that you sort descending, but the index is ascending. When it's about sorting, I'd try to make the index match the sort order exactly:

```
create index idx on posts(hot desc, ...)
```

Comment: thank you! I think I won't need a covering index, but good to know :) I will let MySQL decide whether or not to use it.